# How can i put icon on button in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a window and there is a button on it. I want to put a icon of question mark on that button,how can i do this??

To create button:-

```
HWND button = CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), NULL,
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_ICON, 20, 50, 200, 25,
            hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

To load question mark icon:-

```
HICON hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_QUESTION);
```

To put the icon on button:-

```
SendMessage(button, WM_SETICON, IMAGE_ICON, (LPARAM)hIcon);
```

But icon is not appearing on button.

Comment: Use `BM_SETIMAGE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong message to set the icon to the button. You need to use [`BM_SETIMAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/bm-setimage).